# Can't call the last three names of a list

Tags: python, list

I have made a code on makeblocks or mblock using python. The problem is that I made a list that consist of 6 names and I can't call the last 3  names.

I made a list that consist of 6 names and I can't call the last 3 names, yet I called the first  three so easily!. And when I try to call the last three it calls only one of them  or it calls the whole list. So I need help

This is the code:

```
from mblock import event

names = ['Youssef','Mike','Jhon','Lojy','Jana','Suzan']

@event.greenflag
def on_greenflag():
    while True:
        userques = sprite.input("I will tell you some popular american names. Choose[male/female]names")
        if userques is "male":
            for index in range (3):
                index+1
                print(names[index])
                sprite.say(names[index],2)
        if userques is "female":
            for index in range (3):
                print(names[index])
                sprite.say(names[index],2)
```

Comment: range(3) will always give you 0,1 and 2 .  What have you tried to retrieve the last 3 records in a list?

Comment: Actually... why don't you just have male_names and female_names as two separate lists?

Comment: I can but I am trying to learn more and know how to develop my codes
That is because I am still a beginner

Comment: I tried 6 but it displayed all of them

Comment: Assuming you want to print the first three elements of the list when the users inputs "male" and the last three when the user inputs "female" you would need to change the second range to

range(3,6)

The first range will print elements with indexes 0, 1 and 2, and the second it will print the elements with indexes 3, 4, 5.

Comment: so do you know how to call the last 3 only?

Comment: You increment index using `index+1` but you do not assign it. Did you mean `index += 1` ? The line `index +1` is basically useless in your code as it does not mutate the variable `index`

Comment: Also, you can [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/7786148) lists in Python, so you can do `for item in names[:3]` to iterate over the first 3 items and `for item in names[-3:]`  to iterate over the last 3 items.

Comment: To get the last three via range you might look at `range(5, 2,-1)`